# Segmentation fault when call a python lib in shared hosting

Tags: python, shared-hosting

**Hello**

Im working in A2 shared hosting making a python 3.6.8 app. Before that i did a python env.

When i run the code return
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ci3ut.png)

For example this code return the "Segmentation fault" message

```
import pandas as pd 
print('Hi')
```

When i make a python env with the 2.7 version it works well.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using an outdated version of Python (and as a result, an outdated version of pandas)?

Comment: @Grismar The shared hosting have that version. I don't know if another version of python can be installed.

Comment: @DanielWalker I beg to differ "Officially Python 3.7.1 and above, 3.8, and 3.9." from https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/install.html - all the same, sounds like OP is stuck with it.

Comment: Thanks @DanielWalker. I’m gonna try to update a new python version.

Comment: I just downloaded Python 3.6.8 (on 64-bit Windows 10), installed `virtualenv`, created an environment, installed pandas with `pip install pandas` and executed the code from your sample. That doesn't cause issues - what OS are you using? What else may be installed causing the issue?

Comment: The shared hosting where i am executing the code has linux. @Grismar. In my pc i run the code in macos and doesn't cause issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution Thanks for everything.

The solution was a install a new versión of python following this article of A2hosting.

[This link](https://www.a2hosting.com.mx/kb/developer-corner/python/using-a-newer-version-of-python)